# Insert paragraph breaks before images

Tags: image, vba, ms-word

How can I create a macro to insert paragraph breaks before each image in a file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you are asking _how to create a macro?_, StackOverflow is not the place for such a broad and nonspecific question. If you've written a macro that doesn't work, please show the macro, and explain why it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are of `InlineShapes` type then the code below will do the trick:

```
Sub InsertParagraphBeforeInlinShapes()

    Dim iSHP As InlineShape
    For Each iSHP In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

        ActiveDocument.Range(iSHP.Range.Start, _
                                iSHP.Range.Start).InsertParagraphBefore

    Next iSHP

End Sub
```